# Hibernate does not read @Column when fetching data via @Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I made a custom method that applies a @Query annotation to fetch data from a SQL DB. That method uses a String along with a Pageable as argument. That Pageable carries my paging information, such as page requested, limit of occurrences, sort direction and property.

Whenever my Pageable passes a property name for sorting, Hibernate uses that same name to look for a column on the DB, even though I annotated another column name on the model. I did not have this problem with example queries, or derived method implementations.

I have already tried the configuration below, without any change to the way Hibernate looks for the column name. How can I make Hibernate look for the correct column name on the DB?

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit- 
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical- 
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Example: If my pageable has "projectName" as property name for the model, Hibernate will look for a projectName column, and not "PROJECT_NAME", as annotated on the model. I have been using Hibernate for some queries, and this problem started happening ever since I began using @Query.

Query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM dbo.DW_DOCUMENT WHERE (USER_CREATED LIKE ?1 OR 
PROJECT_NAME LIKE ?1 OR PRIORITY LIKE ?1) AND (DOCUMENT_STATUS = 'Canceled' 
OR STATUS = 'Canceled')", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Autopilot_Queue> findQuickCanceledStr(@Param("search") String search, 
Pageable page);
```

Model:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Entity
@Table(name="DW_DOCUMENT")
@Component
public class Autopilot_Queue {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "PROJECT_NAME")
private String projectName;
@Column(name = "PRIORITY")
private String priority;
@Column(name = "DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE")
private String template;
@Column(name = "STATUS")
private String processStatus;
@Column(name = "DOCUMENT_LANGUAGE")
private String language;
@Column(name = "DOCUMENT_STATUS")
private String documentStatus;
@Column(name = "USER_CREATED")
private String user;

public Autopilot_Queue() {

}

public Autopilot_Queue(Integer id, String projName, String priority, String statusProcess, String template, String language, String statusDocument, String user) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.projectName = projName;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.template = template;
    this.processStatus = statusProcess;
    this.language = language;
    this.documentStatus = statusDocument;
    this.user = user;
}

public Autopilot_Queue(int id, String projName, String priority, String statusProcess, String template, String language, String statusDocument, String user) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.projectName = projName;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.template = template;
    this.processStatus = statusProcess;
    this.language = language;
    this.documentStatus = statusDocument;
    this.user = user;
}

public Integer getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

public String getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(String priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public String getProcessStatus() {
    return processStatus;
}

public void setProcessStatus(String processStatus) {
    this.processStatus = processStatus;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public String getDocumentStatus() {
    return documentStatus;
}

public void setDocumentStatus(String documentStatus) {
    this.documentStatus = documentStatus;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getTemplate() {
    return template;
}

public void setTemplate(String template) {
    this.template = template;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying a *native* query.  That in itself is supported, but [the Spring Data documentation](http://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) notes that:

> **Spring Data JPA does not currently support dynamic sorting for native
>   queries**, because it would have to manipulate the actual query
>   declared, which it cannot do reliably for native SQL. You can,
>   however, use native queries for pagination by specifying the count
>   query yourself [...]

(Emphasis added.) Thus, if you want to control sort order then your options are either to use a JPQL query instead, or to build the desired sort order into the query with an `ORDER BY` clause.  I'm not immediately seeing why the former would not be an option for the query presented, and the latter certainly is an option.

Comment: But isnt it simply a matter of column name translation? The query applies sort correcty when I manually translate projectName to "PROJECT_NAME" for example.

Comment: Hibernate is just not using that property name to look for a @Column annotation to get the corresponded mapping to the DB.